# Repeated PostgreSQL 8.x-9.x-8.x-9.x upgrades and downgrades

Tags: postgresql

What can I expect if, after upgrading from postgres 8.x to 9.x and running pg_upgrade *with the --link option*, I "downgrade" back to 8.x (meaning, I shut off the pg-9 daemon and start the pg-8 daemon)?

In particular, suppose that while I was in pg-9 I inserted some data into tables?  Can I expect to find that data after I downgrade back to pg-8?  Does it depend on whether the tables I inserted that data into were already in existence at the time of my pg_upgrade?
And (call me perverse) suppose I reupgrade to pg-9, re-redowngrade to pg-8, and so on many times.  Are there any guarantees, or am I taking my chances?

I've done some small-scale tests.  What I find is that after the first downgrade, I'm back *roughly* to the data I had before I ran pg_upgrade.  Roughly, not exactly.  And with each upgrade-downgrade cycle, it seems to get more "roughly".

Now I can live with the "roughly" part.  What I'd really hate, though, is if after one too many re-re-re-upgrade/downgrade, I ended up with an irretrievably corrupted DB.  Should that be a worry?

Finally, I do know about pg_dump, but for reasons of time and storage I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish by repeated upgrades and downgrades?

Comment: Well, postgresql is one piece of an overall product I'd like to ship.  The current version of my product comes bundled with postgres-8 while the next version will come with postgres-9.  So I'm just interested in what my users will experience if they upgrade to *my* new version but then, feeling unhappy about it for whatever reason, they decide to downgrade to my older version.  And then, perhaps getting their courage back up they decide to re-upgrade.

Comment: In the interest of preserving your users' data, it's probably best to require a dump-and-reload in the event of a downgrade.  It's cumbersome, sure, but it's better than dataloss.

Comment: That would be the ideal thing to do.  Nonetheless, I'd like to get some kind of fix on a worst possible scenario.  If I downgrade from pg9 to pg8 and there insert data, then when I go back to pg9 my metadata will be out of sync with the data that's actually there (since the pg8 and pg9 data files are hard links of each other).  Could this out-of-syncness result in an unusable pg9 DB?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider `pg_upgrade` to be an *irreversible* step. If you want to be able to undo the changes, don't use `--link` so the old database remains in place and unchanged. If the user goes back to the old database they'll lose changes made since they upgraded.

You should really provide a backup and restore tool the user can use, so they can make a backup, upgrade to the new version, and if unhappy downgrade then restore the backup. For bonus points, make your backup tool compatible of producing backward-compatible backups, so a backup from $newversion can be restored to $oldversion.